# enum inside a structure

Tags: c++, enums, structure

I am trying this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace
{
    typedef enum
    {
        orange,
        banana,
        apple
    }fruit;
}

typedef struct Information
{
    int number;
    namespace::fruit choice;
}Information;

void input_structure()
{
    Information info;

    info.number = 5;
    info.choice = orange;

    printf("Number = %d\n", info.number);
    printf("Choice: %d\n", info.choice);
}

int main()
{
    input_structure();

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with this error:

```
error C2039: 'choice' : is not a member of 'Information'
```

Although I understand what this error is, I am not able to rectify it.
Can somebody help me to solve this?

Comment: Give the namespace a name and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

When referring to an entity inside a namespace, you shouldn't qualify it with the `namespace` keyword. All you need is just the namespace's name e.g. `std::vector`.  Since you have an unnamed (anonymous) namespace, just refer to it as-is.  Removing it makes the program compile and run: [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bac57966ce43f81a).  If you have to refer to something in the global namespace you may use `::` e.g. `::f();`.

As an aside, you don't need the `typedef` since this is C++; you can just write

```
struct Information
{
    int number;
    fruit choice;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors I get are

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings    -c -o 35546727.o 35546727.cpp
35546727.cpp:16:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘namespace’
     namespace::fruit choice;
     ^
35546727.cpp: In function ‘void input_structure()’:
35546727.cpp:24:10: error: ‘Information’ has no member named ‘choice’
     info.choice = orange;
          ^
35546727.cpp:27:33: error: ‘Information’ has no member named ‘choice’
     printf("Choice: %d\n", info.choice);
                                 ^
```

The first error is the one to deal with.  An anonymous namespace has no name; it is not called 'namespace'.  So you should just write:

```
    fruit choice;
```

instead of

```
    namespace::fruit choice;
```

in your definition of `Information`.

---

Note that `typedef struct foo {} foo` is a C way of writing things; in C++ we write simply

```
struct Information
{
    int number;
    fruit choice;
};
```